# MySQL: When to apply the where condition check and filesort operation in this simple case?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, explain

Table: actor

```
-------------------------
| id | actor_id | notes |
-------------------------
| 1  |   1      |  'a'  |
| 2  |   1      |  'a'  |
| 3  |   2      |  'a'  |
| 4  |   3      |  'a'  |
| 5  |   3      |  'a'  |
| 6  |   1      |  'a'  |
-------------------------
```

SQL

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT id, actor_id, @rownum FROM actor
WHERE @rownum <= 1
ORDER BY notes, LEAST(0, @rownum := @rownum + 1);
```

This is an example taking from *Making evaluation order deterministic* section, *Chapter6 Query Performance Optimization*, in *High Performance MySQL, 3rd Edition*.

According to the text from the book, and the 'Using where; Using temporay; Using filesort' result of the *Extra* field of the explain SQL, and [this](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24) post, I was expected the above SQL will print out each row of the actor table.

I thought all of the six rows would be put in into an temporary table using the '@rownum <= 1' where filter first, then filesort appled to this temp table, and six rows printed out finally.

But the real result is only 2:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | actor_id | @rownum |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 |
|  2 |        1 |       2 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Could someone explain the details of the execution plan in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `extra` information are flags, they do not describe the order these operations are executed (though they are printed in the usual order).

The reason you get your result is simply that this is what is supposed to happen when you evaluate in-row-variables in mysql. They are evaluated row-wise.

The optimizer will not change the resultset of a query, it's his job to always return the same rows no matter what exact execution plan will be chosen, but in the fastest (or "cheapest") way possible. (Though you can sometimes gain some insights from the order of the resultset).

So the sql query describes what you want to get, it doesn't care about the optimizer (though you can obviously "help" the optimizer sometimes), it doesn't care if the optimizer will use ordering after selecting. So if some algorithm will be faster if you do the ordering first and then the select, or if the execution would do something completely different, you would still expect the same resultset.

The sql code to express what you are thinking of (first selecting, then ordering) would look like

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT *, @rownum FROM 
(SELECT id, actor_id, @rownum, notes FROM actor
 WHERE @rownum <= 1
) as subquery
ORDER BY notes, LEAST(0, @rownum := @rownum + 1);
```

This will give you all rows (with inner `@rownum = 0` and outer `@rownum = 1..6`), since the ordering and thus the evaluation is done afterwards. The `explain` will have 2 rows here (inner and outer part).

But there is still some uncertainty when using the same variable several times in a query: it's execution order (for one row) is actually not defined, so it is possible that another version of mysql will behave a little bit differently. Here, it evaluated the `order by` before the `select`, you can see that because you got `1` and `2` for the column @rownum, not `0` and `1`.

Comment: I don't think you got my point. This case was take from a section which dedicated to "User defined variable" and its execution time among the various SQL execution process of the book *High Performance MySQL*. The following SQL will also give the same 6 rows as yours:  SELECT id, actor_id, (at)rownum := (at)rownum + 1 FROM actor WHERE (at)rownum <= 1 ORDER BY notes. And the author said this is because **the ORDER BY added a filesort and the WHERE is evaluated before the filesort**.

Comment: @IFree you are right, I didn't get your point. But I am pretty sure the `where` is actually executed first. I guess the `where` condition is applied twice: the first `where`, which will put 6 rows in the temp table, then a filesort, and then, just because it is the expected behaviour of that query, another `where` afterwards. For no `order by`, that is the expected result, and no 2nd `where`-evaluation with `order by` (so 6 rows). With @rownum in order by, I guess I would expect a 2nd `where` (though I would always sort ...

Comment: ... outside of a subquery for a rank, just to be safe). But mostly because "it has always been that way". (I guess the main problem is that the behaviour for variable usage is not 100% logical everywhere, but still constistent). I'm going to think about how to test for that double-where-behaviour.